# How to check if folder or subfolders have been modified since last commit in main branch in git?

Tags: git

My git repo has multiple folder. A unique requirement needs to check if any of the folder has been updated/modified, if so then do something else?
Is there a way in git to check if any folder or its contents have been modified since last commit (in main)?
suggestions?

Comment: Is this your question: Is there a way in git to check if any file or folder of my local repo has been modified since the last commit that's recorded in the remote repo (the one I push to)?

Comment: yes most likely. as i said earlier i have multiple folders and i need to write a script to see what folder or its contents have been changed and then iterate it to create a tgz and deploy it. I just need to know how do i check and see what folders have been modified.let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not *store* **folders**: Git stores only **files**, keeping them inside **commits**—so it really just *stores* commits, which then in turn store files.  A file may have a name like `path/to/file`.  This is not a folder named `path` containing a folder named `to` containing a file named `file`.  It is just a file named `path/to/file`.  (This odd storage system is an outgrowth of Git's *index*, which is incapable of holding folders, only files.  There are some tricks that sort of work, using submodules to fake things out, that will allow you to convince Git to create an empty folder.  But in general Git only stores commits-that-store-files.  When *extracting* a commit's archive-of-files—each commit acts like a full `tgz` archive of these files—Git knows that *your OS* requires folders, and will create them as needed.)

That aside: it's easy to have Git compare the stored contents of some *commit* to some set of files.  The most user-oriented Git command that does this is `git diff`.  This command can:

- compare two commits in your repository;
- compare one commit to what you have in your *working tree* in your repository;
- compare one commit to what you have in Git's *index;*
- compare one commit to a set of files that's in an independent folder (not part of any working tree);
- compare two independent folders that are entirely outside Git;

and several more operations.  For full details, see [the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

The diff operation can be described this way:

- Place one file, or set of files, on the left side of your screen.
- Place the other file or set of files on the right.
- Play a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference): describe *how to modify* the left image to make it match the right image.

To have `git diff` use the latest commit that appears on some branch named *`B`* as the left side here, simply use the name *`B`* as the first (i.e., left-side) and perhaps only commit specifier.  In general, you might wish to use `git diff --name-status` here, so that instead of showing you *how to change* each file, it just says *whether* each file was changed, or whether some file(s) were added or deleted.

Since Git only deals in *files* at this level, it's up to you to turn `path/to/file` into whatever folder name you want (`path` or `path/to`), should you wish to consolidate the output from `git diff` in some way.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I could do it now with a few lines of code in python which actually does a comparison of latest commit with the previous commit in main. and then from the output i filter the folders which i need to see were modified.

Comment: Yes, it's usually easy to write in any language that either has a diff engine, or can invoke one (such as `git diff`). :-) In fact, since you're looking for binary "same/different" flags, you don't even need a real diff engine, just a file-comparator.

Answer (score 0):

The command `git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no my-directory/` should do the trick. I use this in a pre-commit hook to avoid commits to a subtree directory.